# Submitting a transaction from cardano-cli with Nami Wallet

Tags: cardano-cli, nami

I am aware that there is an issue regarding the fact that serialization-lib and cardano-cli are not compatible

Converting the array into a Map is not the solution because in my case I also have the datum (I am interacting with a smart contract)

How should I convert the cbor transaction
"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"

to be Nami compatible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The solution remains the same. You must convert the array into the map, commonly done by signing it with throw away keys. Then you get the transaction with the serialization library, free the witness set then create and set new required signers and then reassemble the transaction while making sure to include the datum and redeemer (which can also be found in the map). Alternatively, you can use the `--cddl-format` in cardano-cli to yield the cbor encoding that is compatible with cardano-ledger (and thus nami).

Comment: "reassemble the transaction while making sure to include the datum and redeemer", can you expand on that? Do I need to send the tx back to the back-end after signing it with Nami?

Comment: --cddl-format worked almost fine but when I tried to submit adding the signature it fails :/